# Kotlinx Serialisation for nested class

Tags: kotlinx.serialization

I am working on Kotlinx Serialisation and there is an error in serialising nested class.

> This class is not serializable automatically because it has primary constructor parameters that are not properties

The workaround is to go with polymorphism using abstract/sealed class or with property variables, which is not the right way for my usecase. A sample code is given below.

```
@Serializable
open class A(val s: String) {}

@Serializable    //Error here
class B(s: String, val i: Int): A(s) {}
```

Is there any workaround for this?